# Information geometry tutorial

Tags: references, intuition, information-geometry

I would like to know more about the topic of information geometry, but i don't want to delve deeply into it. The resources i found was either too complicated or just very messy presentations like this one:

http://www.riken.jp/lab-www/theory/colloquium/amari.pdf

can someone give me some useful links for motivation and use?

Comment: What is your background? Why do you want to learn information geometry?

Comment: My background is in machine learning, i was just curious about information geometry and how it relates to likelihood function.

Comment: Google for the following "machine learning and information geometry" (without the quotes). Seems to give some interesting hits. If those are not suitable, explain why.

Answer (score 4):

You can give a try to:

- [Information Geometry and Its Applications: An Overview](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-47058-0_1)
- [Pattern learning and recognition on statistical manifolds: An information-geometric review](https://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~nielsen/FN-SIMBAD2013.pdf)