# How to learn information geometry from a statistical background

Tags: information-geometry

I have started learning information geometry from the book Differential geometry and Statistics by M.K.murray and J.W. Rice.But I am facing huge difficulties in understanding mathematics behind it.
I have an understanding of real analysis ,and linear algebra.
Please tell me how to begin with this topic.

Comment: Duplicate:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239809/information-geometry-tutorial

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Information geometry tutorial](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239809/information-geometry-tutorial)